# How can i allign six canvas in a div horizontally and vertically using css

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has six HTML canvas in it. How can i allign three canvas horizontally in one block occupying 50% of the screen and the other three canvas to the bottom of the other block s in the added image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cggsk.png)

my current code

```
<div id="_jscontrol" class="chartjscontrol">
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
</div>
```

.chartjscontrol{
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is give the `canvas` elements a width of one-third of the screen, with `width: 33.333%`, along with `float: left`.

You can use `vw` and `vh` in place of 'viewport width' and 'viewport height' respectively, making the elements occupy 100% of the total width and height of the page.

In my example, I've created a margin of `20px` by using `canvas:nth-of-type(n+4)` to select only the bottom three elements. I've also subtracted this from the height of each element, to ensure that they take up the correct height. I've also given each canvas a border in my example, and taken this into consideration for the widths:

```css
.myCanvas {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.333% - 2px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: calc(50vh - 20px);
}

.myCanvas:nth-of-type(n+4) {
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="_jscontrol" class="chartjscontrol">
  <canvas class="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas class="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas class="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas class="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas class="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas class="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Also note that you have multiple IDs of `myCanvas` in your example, which is invalid markup. I've replaced these with classes in my answer :)

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flex layout and `align-self` the last 3 to `flex-end`

```css
.chartjscontrol {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1806px;
  height: 1000px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

canvas:nth-child(1n+4) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="_jscontrol" class="chartjscontrol">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:block" width="600" height="400">
</canvas>
</div>
```